# Keeping textboxes hidden and shown in synch

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've used [StickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/) jQuery plugin to have header of my page-wide table stick to the top. I want to add filter box (regular `INPUT` text tag) into table's `TH`. The problem is if I enter the text into the inputbox before the header is cloned (to be "sticky"), the clone doesn't have text I enterd. An vice versa. As far as I can tell there's no event triggered when a html element is hidden/un-hidden. How can I keep the text between original header and cloned "sticky" header synchronized? Either by modifying plugin (I don't know jQuery that well), or non-jQuery way.

```
<table id="xxx">
    <colgroup>
       <col span="1" style="width: 100px" />
       <col span="1" style="width: 200px" />
       <col span="1" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="bID">ID</th>
            <th class="bStatus"><span class="statusCol">Status</span></th>
            <th class="bSummary">Summary <input type="text" name="firstname"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="can">
            <td class="bID">...</td>
            <td class="bStatus">...</td>
            <td class="bSummary">...</td>
        </tr>
```

**EDIT:**

`jsfiddle.net/tsLxz` thanks! after it loads, enter any text in the text box, then scroll down -- text disappears from the box; scroll back up - appears again. i understand why, but don't know how to synch.

Comment: can you show your problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tsLxz/ thanks! after it loads, enter any text in the text box, then scroll down -- text disappears from the box; scroll back up - appears again. i understand why, but don't know how to synch.

Comment: Something I noticed, if you scroll once, then enter text, you can scroll down and it sticks, except for when you go ALL the way to the top again.

Comment: it happens because sticky row is a clone/copy of the original with copies of all controls (?). original is hidden, then visible sticky copy is created. When after page load we enter text - it is in original text box, after sticky is displayed -- copy of the original text box is displayed. so, copy is created without it's contents (maybe before we enter the text?). and when you scroll back up, original is displayed with content different from what's in it's clone... this is how I understand it, anyways.

Comment: @flamey see My answer and DEMO. if it helped please accept as answer. Sorry for delayed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Script... [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLxz/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#defectsList').stickyTableHeaders();
});


$(document).on('change','[name=filterBox]',function(){

    $(document).data('Textval',$(this).val());
}); 
$(window).scroll(function(){
          $('[name=filterBox]').val($(document).data('Textval'));
});
```

NOTE:  I am using `change` event which is fired after the text box is `tabbed off`. so remember to `tab off` or focus on some other element  before starting scrolling.

Comment: it seems to work, thank you so much! I changed onChange event to onKeyup, and it seems to work without the need to "tab off" the text box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the fact you're nesting the `<input>` element inside the `th` tag.  If you scroll really slowly you'll see it appended to the top of the document. Maybe try using `appendTo()` from javascript to see if you can dynamically append the content to that particular header (give it an id or a different class name).  Just an idea I got from fiddling around with it.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the author of the plugin suggested more elegant solution:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'th input', function(e){
    $('th input[name="' + e.target.name +'"]').val(e.target.value);
});
```